# Api pdfbox-app-2.0.2 How I can to split pdf file?

Tags: java, api, pdf, split, pdfbox

I would like to split a PDF file, I wrote the code, I don't have any error, but not function, I don't receive the files. My Pdf document has 3 pages, I would like that in my desktop appear three file of one page.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.Splitter;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;

public class CutPDF {

    private static File file ;
    private static String filePath = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\EmailTest.pdf";


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        file = new File(filePath);
        PDDocument document;
        document = PDDocument.load(file);

        Splitter splitter = new Splitter();
        List<PDDocument> listOfSplitPages;
        listOfSplitPages = splitter.split(document);
        Iterator<PDDocument> iterator = listOfSplitPages.listIterator();

        // I am using variable i to denote page numbers. 
        int i = 1;
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            PDDocument pd = iterator.next();
                // Saving each page with its assumed page no.
                pd.save("C:\\Users\\Desktop " + i++ + ".pdf");
        }        
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has created files that are named

```
c:\users\desktop 1.pdf
c:\users\desktop 2.pdf
c:\users\desktop 3.pdf
```

i.e. the "\" is missing after the p.

Thus the correct code should be

```
pd.save("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\" + i++ + ".pdf");
```

or

```
pd.save(new File("C:\\Users\\Desktop", i++ + ".pdf"));
```

Note that 2.0.2 has a problem with splitting, the files will be too big. If you're splitting more than one page, use 2.0.1 or 2.0.3 (when it comes out, i.e. in a few months / weeks).